# df.to_sql getting error: Error converting data type nvarchar to float

Tags: python, sql

I am reading a text file with already set delimiters and trying to upload it into a database with already existing table in it.

From there I am getting the above mentioned error. The structure of the table in the database is supposed to be the same as the one I have from the text file.

```
df = pd.read_csv(txtfile, sep = ";")
df.to_sql(table_name,con=engine,if_exists = 'append', schema = schema_name, index =False)
```

Any ideas how to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

What is the decimal separator for float? Try replacing the comma with a dot.

Answer (score 0):

Being explicit about datatypes should at the very least give you a more helpful error message and at best resolve this issue. [You can pass in a data types dictionary](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) when reading from pandas like so:

```
pd.read_csv(txtfile, sep = ';', dtype={'column_a':np.float64}
```

Doing this should let you be explicit about the file types you want to pass into sql. Failing that, [you can do the same when writing to SQL](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) (this works best in conjunction with SQL alchemy's types module)